# TextView in all projects moved to the right

Tags: android, button, textview, center

This is easily the weirdest problem I've ever faced.

So today, I created a new Android Project. The first layout xml had just a textview that has the following properties (its inside a relative layout):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="124dp"
    android:background="#80ffffff"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:textSize="48dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

What I wanted was to have a textview that has text in its center. But the text STARTS from the center and goes out of screen towers the right side.

So I thought I must be doing something wrong. I went into one of my older projects (it was also open in eclipse). I opened an XML there, and shockingly, all the text there has also moved to the left (It starts from the center, rather than actually centering the text). It was fine yesterday. Here's the button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/gettingstarted"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/login"
    android:layout_below="@+id/login"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Getting Started"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

I have no idea what happened. Why is the text no longer centered in buttons in all my projects? I'm in a really tough spot right now. Kindly help.

Comment: Have you parsed the xml after edits or did you just save it?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but.. what do you mean PARSED the xml? I just saved it, like I always do lol

Comment: Well it depends on the editor you use which may parse the xml, its like compiling the code. Some languages do require that before the file is run or executed.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse so pressing Ctrl+S is enough. The project is rebuilt automatically once you do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first problem try

```
android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
```

but for your text views in your all projects , it's a general question , maybe it's occured because of changing in your apps theme or projects styles

Comment: The problem in the other projects went away after I restarted eclipse.
And your little snippet worked too :) Now the text is properly centered. Thanks. Marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Minimum time limitation. Done now.